# How should I answer the ESTA question about a passport or national identity card?

Tags: usa, paperwork, esta, applications

The ESTA appliation asks:

> Have you ever been issued a passport or national identity card for travel by any other country?

Does being a resident of Nicaragua count? I have a resident card, not really a passport or ID, but it works as an ID while I am in Nicaragua.

How should I answer the question, yes or no?

It then asks, "Are you a citizen or national of any other country?"

If I am a resident of Nicaragua, should I answer yes or no?

I want to get it right.

Comment: Of what country are you a citizen?

Comment: @Giorgio Not Nicaragua, or they wouldn't have a resident Card as opposed to a national ID

Comment: @Coke agreed, so could not the answer to bpther be yes, that they have a passport issued by another country and that they're a citizen of another country.

Comment: See also https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/117412/esta-national-identity-card-for-travel-by-any-other-country

Answer (score 4):

A national identity card is a type of ID that proves person's citizenship.

They are asking you about those kinds of IDs. Your residency card, drivers license or student card issued by another country and working as an ID in those countries are of no interest for The Department of Homeland Security.

The answer would be '**No**' to both questions.

Comment: The answer to both could be yes, depending on OP's citizenship, which is not indicated by the question, only that they are resident.

Comment: @Giorgio next time you downvote - give an example. ok?

Comment: @Giorgio That's extremely unlikely (given the wording of the question) and not what the question is about. In fact, it does not depend on the OP's “citizenship” (singular) at all but on whether they have several as “other“ in “Have you ever been issued a passport or national identity card for travel by any other country?” means “other than that you are using as the main citizenship for your submission”. It makes little sense to down vote this answer based on this concern.

Answer (score 2):

> I have a resident card, not really a passport or ID, but it works as an ID while I am in Nicaragua.

Based on this you're **not** a Nicaraguan citizen, but a foreign resident.

Passports and national ID cards are documents tied to citizenship, so the answer to the question is "no".

Comment: You can of course be citizen of Nicaragua without having passport or national identiy card. You would have _the right_ to have them, but you don't have them.

Answer (score 0):

You answer whatever is the truth. If you ever had a passport from Nicaragua (even if you are not a citizen anymore) the answer to the first question is Yes. Same for national identity card. A resident card is not a passport or national identity card, so if that is all you have and ever had, the answer is No.

The second question is "are you a citizen or national of another country". If you are today a citizen or national of Nicaragu, the answer is Yes. A resident is not a citizen or national. If you were a citizen in the past but are not a citizen anymore, then the answer is "No" because the question is "are you" not "have you ever been".

Answer (score -1):

so what did you answer after? the question states that

> Have you ever been issued a passport or national identity card FOR TRAVEL by any other country?

the thing is, the question states that it's for travel. There no need to wright it because Nicaragua ID cannot be used as a travel document to travel. I have a Panamanian ID and a passport from another country. I am doing this

Comment: A Nicaraguan ID for citizens can be used for travel to the neighbouring countries (Honduras, Panama etc)

Comment: Incorrect answers can get you into deep trouble. Answer the question truthfully, don't interpret it.