# ESTA: Have you ever been issued a Passport or National Identity Card for travel by any other country?

Tags: usa, esta, us-visa-waiver-program

I am naturalized in Germany this year, 2023, and want to spend holidays with relatives in the USA. I renounced my previous citizenship this year.

I am having difficulty answering the above mentioned question. Naturally the answer is yes, and although I do not have the physical copy of my old passport, I still have a scanned copy. It was revoked this year but on the passport itself the expiry is in 2028.

What should I input on the expiration year field, 2023 (because of renunciation) or 2028 (stated on the passport)? If I leave it blank or 0000, would it be bad for my application?

Comment: I would think that if your passport has been revoked, then it's expired.  In my opinion (not an answer...) if it were me I'd put 2023 as when it expired.

Comment: Are you filling out an ESTA application? Is there a blank field for "additional information" If so, it'd be easy enough to include this explanatory information. Also, you might find [this previous question and answers](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/114358/how-should-i-answer-the-esta-question-about-a-passport-or-national-identity-card?rq=1) useful.

Comment: There are no other field where i can explain a bit about the expiration :(., its just a straight forward field like passport numvber and expiry date and nothing more.

Comment: Thanks Midavalo for your input.

Comment: @RamBuoy The application form may include such a blank field at the end of the form.

Comment: DavidRecallsMonica, thanks for your help., to close this thread, i just want to inform that I did what you guys recommended me and it has a positive outcome, Travel is now authorized. :)