Canceled vs Original Expiration Date for Previous Passport in ESTA Application
I'm a newly naturalized British citizen (naturalized in 2024) filling out my ESTA application. Previously, I held Indian citizenship and had an Indian passport valid until 2032.
Under Indian law, when a person acquires foreign citizenship, their Indian citizenship is automatically renounced, and their Indian passport becomes invalid for travel. This is because India does not permit dual citizenship.
In the ESTA application, there's a question: "Have you ever been issued a passport or national identity card for travel by any other country?"
My specific question: For my previous Indian passport, which date should I provide as the expiration date:

The original printed expiration date (2032), or
2024 (the year when the passport became invalid due to my British naturalization)

I want to ensure I'm providing accurate information while completing my ESTA application.

Do Indian authorities know that you get a new nationality? If not, the passport is still valid for them (a "limbo status").

No, I'm in the process of surrendering my passport. Assuming I do that, I will fill the ESTA after that.

I was hoping someone in a similar situation as me - i.e. a cancelled status could provide details if they got an approved ESTA application.

What does "I'm in the process of surrendering my passport" mean? Did you disclose to the Indian authorities that you had taken UK citizenship?  Did you fill out an Indian governent form saying that? Did you physically return your Indian passport to the Indian authorities? Something else?

Yes, I had applied for surrendering my passport to the Indian authorities. They take your existing passport for cancelation and it takes a couple of weeks for them to process it and return the cancelled passport back.

Note: I put in the year my passport was cancelled (2024), rather than it's original expiration year(2032). My ESTA application was approved in less than an hour.

I am fairly certain that it would also have been granted if you had put 2032.  While misrepresentation is grounds for refusal (as well as possibly being a crime under 18 USC 1001), this is only true if the misrepresentation is willful.  As long as you reasonably believe that you are giving the correct answer to the question, there is no misrepresentation, even if your belief arises because of some misinterpretation or misunderstanding.

You should use the original expiry date, as printed on the passport.
The fact that the passport has become invalid before that date does not change the "Expiry" date of the passport.  This is the same situation as when you lose a passport or even just when you renew a passport before it has expired - the Expiry date for the original passport doesn't change.

Seems like there might be conflicting advice, for eg https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/184938/ESTA-have-you-ever-been-issued-a-passport-or-national-identity-card-for-travel I have not been able to get a conclusive answer. I even tried calling the CBP helpline and they didn't provide me an answer.

OTOH the passport is expired (no more valid). Different interpretation of the same wording. If the form allow text, I would write: "2032 (renounced in 2024)"

The field only allows for numerical values.

@samj1912 to be honest, it probably does not matter too much which date you put.  They're not going to deny the ESTA because of that, in any event.
